# php reset static method-scope variable between tests

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a large suite of tests for my php code. Some of that code uses static variables within functions to improve performance. However during testing that can leave the class in an awkward state for subsequent tests.

There is a method `ReflectionClass::setStaticPropertyValue()` that can reset statics in the Class scope, but `ReflectionMethod` only has `getStaticVariables`, and no setter.

`ReflectionMethod` is largely undocumented at php.net, but `getStaticVariables` is returning a copy of the value, so altering that has no effect on the actual class.

I'm currently including code that essentially doesn't use the static variable when running Unit tests, but that is not a satisfying solution. Is there a way to reset a static variable in the method scope? Is there a way to simply clear out the class so all statics are reset?

Edit to add:

```
# Foo.php

class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        static $a = 0;
        $a += 1;
        return $a;
    }
}


# TestFoo.php

class TestFoo extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    private $foo;

    setUp() {
        $foo = new Foo();
    }

    test1() {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $foo->bar());
        $this->assertEquals(2, $foo->bar());
    }

    test2() {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $foo->bar());
    }
}
```

test2 will pass if run separately, but even though a new $foo is created test2 will fail if run after test1.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a [mre] showing the problem?

Comment: Added sample showing static variable in method

Comment: Rewrote as PHPUnit tests.

Comment: Though I want to be clear this is not a question about PHPUnit, it's a question about altering a static variable in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to reset a static variable in the method scope?

In the method scope, yes. If that is what you mean:

```
public function bar($b = null) {
    static $a = 0
    $a = $b ?? $a;
    $a += 1;
    return $a;
}

... ->bar($aWillBeSetTo = 0);
```

> Is there a way to simply clear out the class so all statics are reset?

Not that I know of. If this static is standing in your way, rip it out. Replace it with a private instance variable (property of the class), if you need global static state, make it a static property of that class or make it a global even. Whatever suits you.

There is nothing in reflection what I know of that you can reach it for modification (only reading, you found that as well).

So much with standard userland PHP.

Otherwise [uopz has a function for that: `uopz_set_static()`  — Sets the static variables in function or method scope<sup>*[DOCS]*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-set-static.php).

Comment: Thanks for that response. The static is an implementation detail of the method, and it adds clutter to the class to move it out to a wider scope where it doesn't have meaning. Adding a parameter to the method call would be very impractical for integration testing; the parameter would have to be passed up through a long call chain from the test. Eventually I added an environment test paired with a flag to indicate when to not use the static. At least the ugliness is all in one place. Very curious about uopz now, however.

Answer (score 1):

there is one method teardown which will run after every test so you can use

```
protected function tearDown()
{
  $this->foo::$a=0;
}
```

Comment: That could be in the setUp as well (so I don't have to rely on other tests being well-behaved), but unless my test is flawed, that does not modify a static in the scope of a method.